# Sort array of floats in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I m new to c # . I need to sort arrays aa and bb with have all the items floats. I need to get highest and second highest in boths arrays . How can I sort the array ? I found how to sort arrays of int s , but didn t see how to sort floats . If it s not possible , what other options do I have ?

```
namespace program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float a = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float b = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float c = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float d = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float e = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float f = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

            float[] aa = new float[3];
            aa[0] = a;
            aa[1] = c;
            aa[2] = e;

            float[] bb = new float[3];
            bb[0] = b;
            bb[1] = d;
            bb[2] = f;




            Console.WriteLine( (aa[0]- aa[1]) * (bb[0]-bb[1]) /2 );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely what you did to sort `int`s would work for floats. What exact problem did you have?

Comment: `Array.Sort` has generic overload

Comment: This is easily searched. What was your problem, what didn't you understand?

Comment: Note that finding the largest and second-largest value does not require sorting -- it can be done by processing all the elements only once. Sorting (ordering all the elements) is inherently more expensive.

Comment: This seems a case of the xy problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with the code above, it wasn't clear in your post.

Comment: `Array.Sort(aa);` and `Array.Sort(bb);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array.Sort(yourArray) to sort your array

once you have sorted your array then you can use the indexes to access the first and second items as per your code.

```
     `static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        float a = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        float b = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        float c = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        float d = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        float e = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        float f = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

        float[] aa = new float[3];
        aa[0] = a;
        aa[1] = c;
        aa[2] = e;

        float[] bb = new float[3];
        bb[0] = b;
        bb[1] = d;
        bb[2] = f;

        Array.Sort(aa);
        Array.Sort(bb);




        Console.WriteLine( (aa[0]- aa[1]) * (bb[0]-bb[1]) /2 );

    }`
```

Comment: Could you please add details as to how this would address the OP issue and what the OP did wrong? It would benefit anyone that come's across this solution.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ updated the answer .. sorry I am new to answering the question and  thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It's not a problem, no need to apologize. Thanks for updating your post and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start extracting `ReadSingle` routine:

```
  private static float ReadSingle(string title = null) {      
    while (true) {
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        Console.WriteLine(title);

      if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float result))
        return result;

      Console.WriteLine("Invalid format, please try again.");  
    }
  }
```

then create arrays:

```
  float[] aa = new float[] {
    ReadSingle(),  
    ReadSingle(),
    ReadSingle(), 
  };

  float[] bb = new float[] {
    ReadSingle(),  
    ReadSingle(),
    ReadSingle(), 
  };
```

in general case, when we have to create an array of  `N` items we can use *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  float[] array = Enumerable
    .Range(1, N)
    .Select(i => ReadSingle($"Please, provide item #{i}"))
    .ToArray();
```

Finally, let's add [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_) and bind it all together:

```
namespace program {
  class Program {
    private static float ReadSingle(string title = null) {      
      while (true) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
          Console.WriteLine(title);

        if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float result))
          return result;

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid format, please try again.");  
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
     float[] aa = new float[] {
        ReadSingle(),  
        ReadSingle(),
        ReadSingle(), 
      };

      float[] bb = new float[] {
        ReadSingle(),  
        ReadSingle(),
        ReadSingle(), 
      };

      Array.Sort(aa);
      Array.Sort(bb); 

      Console.WriteLine((aa[0]- aa[1]) * (bb[0] - bb[1]) / 2);
    }
  }
}
```